# Как передать JSON аргументом в nodejs.exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

Есть библиотека для миграции БД (mongo-migrate - https://github.com/afloyd/mongo-migrate), она запускается следующей строкой в терминале nodejs:
`node ./node_modules/mongodb-migrate -runmm -dbc '{"host":"localhost","db":"myDb","port":27017,"username":"user1","password":"pswd1"}' up`
Мне нужно запустить эту команду внутри js-файла, пробую использовать `require('child_process').exec`, Но не могу понять как мне передать этот JSON как параметр в `exec`...
Пробовал так:

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(`node ./node_modules/mongodb-migrate -runmm -dbc '{"host":"localhost","db":"myDb","port":27017,"username":"user1","password":"pswd1"}' up`,
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
    console.log(`${stdout}`);
    console.log(`${stderr}`);
});
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
exec error: Error: Command failed: node ./node_modules/mongodb-migrate -runmm -dbc '{"host":"localhost","db":"myDb","port":27017,"username":"user1","password":"pswd1"}' up
    undefined:1
    '{host:localhost,db:myDb,port:27017,username:user1,password:pswd1}'
    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
```

Такое ощущение что этот `exec` как то форматирует мою исходную строку, и убирает все `"`, и на выходе получается JSON невалидный...

Как мне передать JOSN как аргупент в `require('child_process').exec` что бы он был без изменений?

Comment: Так не обязательно же запускать именно через `child_process`. Раз Вы все равно в работаете в ноде, просто cделайте `require(mongodb-migrate)`, и вызывайте `setDbConfig(<Ваш JSON>)` и потом `run('up')`

Comment: Да, работает если запускать просто скрипт, но если это все написать внтри `grunt` задачи, то почему-то не срабатывает.... Пока что не понимаю почему... Пробую разобраться, а так вроде все работает нормально, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Yaant А в этот `run` как то можна передать номер ревизии для миграцци типа как то так `run('up', 10)`Или за что отвечает этот аргумент `migrationEnd`? `function runMongoMigrate(direction, migrationEnd, next)`

Comment: Не знаю, я даже не знаю, что такое эти самые миграции, для предыдущего комментария это знание не требовалось. :) Судя по коду, этот параметр позволяет указать номер требуемой миграции (чтобы это ни значило).

Comment: @Yaant, Да все именно так, там ошибка уже на моей стороне была, так что все норм спс :)